# Variable uses inside render function of jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have an XML template file which needs to be updated with right value using jinja2,

eg:

```
<xyz controller-version="004-002-010-000">
    <abc>
        <name>**var_HR_EXACT_NAME**</name>
        <type>OPERATION</type>
     </abc>
</xyz>
```

Want to change the value of the variable which is in bold letter

Python code snippet:

```
app_import_dir=/usr/local/app/template
template_file_name=TemplateFileName.xml
temp_template_file=/usr/local/app/template/TemplateFileName.xml
property_variable_name='var_HR_EXACT_NAME'
property_variable='This is the new value'

env=jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(app_import_dir))
raw_template=env.get_template(template_file_name)
final_template=raw_template.render( **property_variable_name** = **property_variable** )

with open(temp_template_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(final_template)
```

Note: I am using two variables inside render function and this replaces the variable with null

But when I am using exect string inside render it works fine. Can someone help me to find the solution, please

Answer (score 0):

> **Answer:**

Looks like we shouldn't use render inside the loop, hence progressed my python script using a dictionary. 
Add all the variables in the dictionary and replaced in one shot using below and it works as expected.

**Code Snippet:**

```
#Create a new dictionary
view = {}

#Add all the variables from loop
view[property_variable_name] = property_variable

env=jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))
raw_template=env.get_template(template_file_name)

#Call dictionary and replace all variable from template
final_template = raw_template.render(**view)
```

Comment: Make sure render is outside of the loop